# Sequence and convergence(limit): $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Someone please help me with this problem with detailed explanation :

Limit of  $\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac13\left(\frac23\right)^n$$

Now, what is $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^n\;$ for $\;|x|<1;$ ?

Comment: Limit as n -->infinity of x^n  should equals 1.... But the condition given that |x| < 1 is somehow confusing

Comment: @user336588 Try computing $(2/3)^2$, $(2/3)^3$, $(2/3)^4$, $(2/3)^5$.  What happens to the size of $(2/3)^n$ as the exponent gets larger? As $n \to \infty$, what value will $(2/3)^n$ approach?

Comment: As the power increases, the value increases as well for (2/3)...

Comment: (2/3)^n is approaching infinity

Comment: @user336588 it cannot approach infinity: the denominator is going to grow faster than the numerator... check your calculations!

Comment: Yeah...... It is approaching zero(0)

Answer (score 0):

Let

(1) $a_n = \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$

Then it's easy to see that:

(2) $a_{n+1} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot a_n$

Let's say we know that the sequence has a limit $L$. Then by letting $n$ go to infinity in (2) we get:

(3) $L = \frac{2}{3} \cdot L$

So $L=0$.

Now we just have to prove that the sequence has a limit. To do this it suffices to note that the sequence is decreasing and is bounded from below by e.g. $0$ (or say any negative number).

Comment: Thanks so much.... I got it... God bless you abundantly